# How To Check Data Integrity Of MySQL Backed Up With skip-lock-tables

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently in a need to back up a database with both innodb and myisam tables. Since the database is huge, using a default mysqldump will almost certainly impact the application. Hence I am left with the only option of using skip-lock-tables. Below are my questions based on the above scenario:

1. I understand that there are database integrity risks associated with skip-lock-tables. But once I have done dumping with skip-lock-tables, is there an easy way to check if the backup was just fine (even by comparing with parent live database) without any inconsistencies.
2. Another doubt worth mentioning is about my database having a mix of innodb and myisam tables. Is my understanding that -skip-lock-tables will work fine both for myisam and innodb correct? If the answer is NO, can I mention both -single-transaction and -skip-lock-tables in same mysqldump command?

Thanks,
Kannan

Answer (score 0):

1. In general, you should never assume that the backup is fine until you actually restored it and verified it as fine. Especially when using skip-lock-tables.
2. For transactional tables such as InnoDB, --single-transaction is a much better option than --lock-tables because it does not need to lock the tables at all.